# How to remove, randomly, rows from a dataframe but from each label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

This is for a machine learning project.

I have a dataframe with 5 columns as features and 1 column as label (Figure A).

I want to randomly remove 2 rows but from each label. 
So, as there are 12 rows (4 for each label); I will end up with 6 rows (2 from each label) (Figure B).

How can I do it? Would it be easier to do it with only numpy?

Figure A

[image]

Figure B

[image]

And here is my code:

```
# THIS IS FOR FIGURE A
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))

label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])

df['label'] = label
df.index=['s1', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's3', 's3', 's3']
df

#THIS IS MY ATTEMPT FOR FIGURE B
dfs = df.sample(n=2)
dfs
```

Comment: I think sklearn has kfold stratified sampling. Look into staying in sklearn before using pandas. Sklearn has lots of built in functions to handle things like this. You can of course use pandas but don't use for this unless you must.

Comment: I want to plot how the accuracy changes when increasing the number of samples (rows). So the removed rows are going to be sent to a classifier and cross validation. So one option is doing it with Pandas and the other one with numpy. Do you know how to do it with numpy using arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With groupby.apply:

```
df.groupby('label', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(2)) \
                                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out: 
           0         1         2         3         4  label
s1  0.433731  0.886622  0.683993  0.125918  0.398787      1
s1  0.719834  0.435971  0.935742  0.885779  0.460693      1
s2  0.324877  0.962413  0.366274  0.980935  0.487806      2
s2  0.600318  0.633574  0.453003  0.291159  0.223662      2
s3  0.741116  0.167992  0.513374  0.485132  0.550467      3
s3  0.301959  0.843531  0.654343  0.726779  0.594402      3
```

A cleaner way in my opinion would be with a comprehension:

```
pd.concat(g.sample(2) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))
```

which would yield the same result:

```
           0         1         2         3         4  label
s1  0.442293  0.470318  0.559764  0.829743  0.146971      1
s1  0.603235  0.218269  0.516422  0.295342  0.466475      1
s2  0.569428  0.109494  0.035729  0.548579  0.760698      2
s2  0.600318  0.633574  0.453003  0.291159  0.223662      2
s3  0.412750  0.079504  0.433272  0.136108  0.740311      3
s3  0.462627  0.025328  0.245863  0.931857  0.576927      3
```

Comment: I have problems when I try to send the dataframe for cross_validation. Is it possible to remove rows from an array instead of a dataframe? Check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072032/how-to-send-a-dataframe-to-scikit-for-cross-validation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty straightforward way. Mix up all the rows with `sample(frac=1)` and then find the cumulative count for each label and select those with values 1 or less.

```
df.loc[df.sample(frac=1).groupby('label').cumcount() <= 1]
```

And here it is with sklearn's stratified kfold. Example [taken from here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
X = df[[0,1,2,3,4]]
y = df.label
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

print(X_train)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.656240  0.904032  0.256067  0.916293  0.262773
1  0.526509  0.555683  0.667756  0.208831  0.699438
4  0.096499  0.688737  0.328670  0.260733  0.834091
5  0.320150  0.602197  0.793404  0.911291  0.269915
8  0.913669  0.171831  0.534418  0.862583  0.994561
9  0.718337  0.256351  0.348813  0.420952  0.622890

print(y_train)

0    1
1    1
4    2
5    2
8    3
9    3
```

Comment: I have problems when I try to send the dataframe for cross_validation. Is it possible to remove rows from an array instead of a dataframe? Check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072032/how-to-send-a-dataframe-to-scikit-for-cross-validation