# How to send a dataframe to scikit for cross validation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to plot the effect of removing samples (rows). Some people call it a "learning curve".

So I thought of using Pandas to remove some rows.

[How to remove, randomly, rows from a dataframe but from each label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067425/how-to-remove-randomly-rows-from-a-dataframe-but-from-each-label#41067425)

But when I want to do cross validation, I get the following error (even after using `df.values` to turn the dataframe into an array):

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import cross_validation

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))
label = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
df['label'] = label

df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(2) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))

X = df1[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]].values
y = df1.label.values
print(X)
print(y)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(1, test_size=0.1)
scoresSSS = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=sss)
print(scoresSSS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right off the bat, with `sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.35)` you're generating an object, not an iterable:

```
>>> type(sss)
    <class 'sklearn.model_selection._split.StratifiedShuffleSplit'>
```

Instead of giving the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` class your entire object (which obviously isn't iterable, thus the error), you need to give it the train/test output of the class's `.split()` method ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)).

Further, your `test_size` param in your `StratifiedShuffleSplit` class is too small. Using `0.1` as you have will throw a `ValueError` because you have 3 unique classes, therefore `0.1` for a test size won't do. And lastly, you're using the default `n_neighbors` param value in your KNeighbors `clf` object. This default value is too large when using such a small data set. Using what you have will throw another `ValueError` due to `n_neighbors <= n_samples`. So in my example below I've upped the test size in your `StratifiedShuffleSplit` object, dropped `n_neighbors` down to 2, and passed the iterables from `sss.split(X, y)` to `cross_validation.cross_val_score`'s `cv` param.

So here is what you want your code to look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import cross_validation

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12, 5))
label=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
df['label'] = label

df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(2) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))


X = df1[[0,1,2,3,4]].values
y = df1.label.values

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.35)

scoresSSS = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=sss.split(X, y))
print(scoresSSS)
```

**Let me just say** that I have no idea what score you're looking to get, and by no means am I claiming that this will optimize your score. However, this will help you get rid of those errors so you can get back to work.